# JAXB xml parser

Tags: xml, jaxb, wsdl

I want to parse a wsdl file with JAXB and return a list of name value pairs.  How would I do this?  I have tried the NETbeans utility that takes the wsdl url and creates a collection of java classes but I do not know how to be able to get a list of name value pairs from these classes.

Answer (score 0):

WSDL is XML and it has an XML Schema. So you can [compile this schema with XJC](https://github.com/highsource/w3c-schemas/tree/master/wsdl/2.0) and use the generated classes to unmarshal WSDL. Then traverse the resulting object structure and extract your name-value pairs (whatever they are). Alternatively, use simply parse WSDL as DOM and traverse the resulting DOM. You don't have to use JAXB for this.

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of the [W3C Schemas Project](https://github.com/highsource/w3c-schemas) mentioned above.